# How to add view at runtime without from ViewModel in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a mainGrid in Mainwindow. The mainGrid have a context menu. That context menu is binding to the ViewModel. When the user clicks the context menu item, new View is adding to the maingrid at runtime. Before I added the view from ViewModel when the context menu item is a click. But now only I know view type using in ViewModel is a violation. Please, anyone gives a simple example or links to refer how to add the view without from ViewModel.

```
             <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Add new Grid">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=AddNewGridCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName="mainGrid"}"/>                                        
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Grid.ContextMenu>
            </Grid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
private ICommand addNewGridCommand;
public ICommand AddNewGridCommand => addNewGridCommand ?? (addNewGridCommand = new RelayCommand(addGrid, canAddGrid));

private void addGrid(object obj)
{
    // Some UI like below
    Grid newGrid = new Grid()
    {
       Height = 100, Background = Brushes.Gray
    }
   ((obj) as Grid).Children.Add(newGrid);
}
```

Comment: You can use the `Click` event on `MenuItem` and handle it in C# class (not the ViewModel, the _YourViewName.xaml.cs_ one). Here  is an example of how to use and handle it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452760/c-sharp-wpf-context-menu-item-click-event-returns-null

Comment: @Simonca, Thanks for your reply, I follow mvvm on my project. So code behind is not used. If you have any idea to add the view without from viewmodel please share.

Comment: MVVM states that code regarding View should not be in ViewModel class but it can be in the code behind class. If your code is independent from the ViewModel then you can write it in _.xaml.cs_ file.

Comment: See [Open File Dialog MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043918/open-file-dialog-mvvm/43756154#43756154)

Comment: Why do you need to create a `Grid` in code? Have you considered using `DataTemplate`s instead?

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks for your reply, For the first time empty grid is shown. When user click the context menu item then only user have to add that Grid UI dynamically at runtime. For the first time we don't have to create that Grid UI at runtime only we have to create that Grid UI

Comment: Just don't create any UI components in code. You tagged your question as MVVM, but I don't see any MVVM approach. Where are your view-models and data templates?